# Restricting entering same input to dynamic textbox mvc5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view where it has a dynamic input.

This is the code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Attribute"))
{
<input type="text" id="newtypevalue" />
<input type="button" value="Add Text" id="addtypevalue" />
<div id="typevaluelist">
// Generate inputs for existing items and in case of returning the view
foreach(var item in Model.typevalue)
{
  <div class="typevalue">
    <input type="text" name="typevalue" value="@item" />
    <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
}
</div>
....
}
// Hidden template for adding new items (outside the form element)
<div id="new" style="display:none;">
<div class="typevalue">
<input type="text" name="typevalue" />
<button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>

//scripts for adding and deleting items
$('#addtypevalue').click(function() {
var clone = $('#new').clone().children('div'); // copy the template
clone.find('input').val($('#newtypevalue').val()); // update text
$('#typevaluelist').append(clone); // add it to the DOM
$('#newtypevalue').val(''); // clear initial text box
});
$('#typevaluelist').on('click', '.delete', function() {
$(this).closest('.typevalue').remove(); // remove it from the DOM
});
```

I want to restrict user adding the same text(a existing value in the list) to dyanamic textbox. I tried it like this in the view.

```
 @foreach(var item in Model.typevalue){
 if(!Model.typevalue.Contains(item))
 {
      <div class="typevalue">
      <input type="text" name="typevalue" value="@item" />
      <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
      </div>
 }
 }
```

But this is not working. Pls help me with the correct way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@foreach()` is razor code as is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view (it cannot be used for evaluating dynamically added items).

Give your inputs a class name (both inside the `foreach` loop and the one in the template)

```
<input type="text" class="typevalue" name="typevalue" />
```

Then in the buttons .`click` event you can check if any existing inputs have that the value

```
$('#addtypevalue').click(function() {
  var isDuplicate = false;
  // get the value of the item to be added
  var value = $('#newtypevalue').val();
  // get all existing values
  $('.typevalue').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == value) {
      isDuplicate = true;
      alert('duplicates not allowed');
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (!isDuplicate) {
    var clone = $('#new').clone().children('div'); // copy the template
    clone.find('input').val(value); // update text
    $('#typevaluelist').append(clone); // add it to the DOM
    $('#newtypevalue').val(''); // clear initial text box
  }
});
```

Side notes:

1. This is only checking for exact case matches, so you may want to
   convert the values to lowercase before checking if you want (say)
   "item" and "Item" to be considered duplicates.
2. This will give client side validation, but you must still validate
   on the server.

Comment: Yes it worked. Converted to lowercase as well when checking. Thanks a lot for the help.. :)